# Ck editor not show in popup javascript

Tags: javascript, html, popup, ckeditor, popupwindow

i put code ckeditor in my website, but ck editor not showing in popup javascript, previously i try put ckeditor not using popup. This ck editor work.
but i put in javascript popt not working.

**This is my screenshoot using javascript popup** 
[image]

**This is my screenshoot not using javascript popup**
[image]

**This is my script**

```
<script src="element/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
        //ADD News
function news_add()
    {
        var content = '<div id="dialog_confirm_add" title="Create News"> ';
                    content += '        <table width="100%"> ';
                    content += '        <tr >';
                    content += '            <td width="35%">Title</td>';
                    content += '            <td>:</td>';
                    content += '            <td width="65%"><input  style="width:100%" type="text" name="title" id="title" value=""  class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td>';
                    content += '        </tr>';
                    content += '        <tr>';
                    content += '            <td>Content</td>';
                    content += '            <td>:</td>';
                    content += '            <td><textarea  style="width:100%" name="content" id="content" value=""  class="ckeditor" /></textarea></td>';
                    content += '        </tr>';
                    content +='     </table>';
                    content +='</div>';
                    $('body').append(content);

        $('#dialog_confirm_add').dialog({
            resizable: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 200, 
            modal: true,
            close: function destroy_dialog() {
                $( this ).dialog( 'destroy' );

                var bd = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                var dlg = document.getElementById('dialog_confirm_add');
                bd.removeChild(dlg);
            },
            buttons: {
                'Save': function() {

                                var data=[];    
                                var data_site_grid="";
                                insert_data();
                            mydata=[];
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
                    mydata=[];

                }
            }
        });

    }
        </script>
```

Comment: It looks like you are dynamically adding HTML elements onto the page.
In that case, you will have to re-initialize ckeditor to rescan elements and add the editor code.
Further, if you are adding the editor to a pop-up window, you will need to include the ckeditor js file in the popup window as it opens another browser session.

Comment: can  you give reference for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initialize the new textarea that you are inserting
append the ckeditor script after the new elements:

```
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.type='text/javascript';
s.src='//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard/ckeditor.js';
$('body').append(s);
```

As long as the ckeditor.js is included on the page, this should rescan the page for the textarea element and change to the ckeditor.

http://jsfiddle.net/96d9102L/1/

Comment: i put like this > http://pastebin.com/yQdcBUuR
this result like this > http://i.imgur.com/fka57Sc.png

Comment: work it, but i click again this ck editor not show again..
can you have a solution

Comment: please help me. when i click again this ck editor not show again